# Is it okay to ask a question looking for research publications?

Tags: discussion, research, academic

Is it okay to ask a question on StackOverflow that looks for information on research publications (in the field of software of course)? These may not necessarily a programming question, but they do relate to software. For instance, would the following questions:
*Research on the quantity of reported vs. unreported bugs in open-source software?*
*Publications on the effectiveness of pair programming?*
*Has there been surveys of the mental models held by novice programmers?*
...be suitable?

I believe these should be allowed as they not only provide a mechanism to complement the likes of Google Scholar or the ACM digital library, but they would also give an idea of the *reputation* of the research. And while they may not be related to the *act of programming*, they could definitely be related to the *field of programming*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd vote "yes" - so long as they're not trying to steal content.

But as long as they're trying to find legit sources, or learn *how* to find said sources, I think it's great.

It has the benefit of being a launching point for others interested, too

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely! This doesn't have to be purely academic either, as the expamples you mentioned would be useful in justifying software development practices to managers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say yes if you are upfront about your intent.

Answer (score 0):

Put me in the "yes" column as long as the research is somehow defensibly useful to developers.  I wouldn't be interested in seeing a bunch of research questions showing up that are related to programming but really represent content more useful to non-developer communities.